# Como echoar um valor antes de ele estar disponível?

Tags: php

Tenho um site no qual faço uma SQL que retorna os registros e a quantidade de registros que eu preciso mostrar no site. Por algum motivo que não vem a questão, eu não tenho mais a possibilidade de capturar esta variável antes do header.

Tenho que colocar os dados entre parênteses que ficam no topo do site.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este resultado retorna pra mim através de um `$_POST['enviar']` o resultado da SQL e a quantidade de registros que são inseridos já abaixo do header. Como colocar a quantidade de registros nesse **"Resultados()**"?

O código abaixo mostra bem o que estou tentando fazer: pegar a `$qteRegistros` e puxá-lo pra cima.

```
<?php

     echo $qteRegistros; <--------------------
     $qteRegistros = "380";

?>
```

Comment: Não entendi a dúvida, você deseja imprimir o valor da variável antes de atribuir?

Comment: O código é executado na sequência em que está escrito. Troque as duas últimas linhas de lugar.

Comment: Não posso trocar de lugar. Como o PHP é ultra fantástico, quero saber se ele faz isso. Alguma coisa haver com `global`????

Comment: Por que causa, motivo, razão ou circunstância você não pode trocar as linhas de lugar? Oo

Comment: Eu faço uma SQL e retorno a quantidade de registros e preciso mostrar a quantidade de registros lá no topo do site !!!

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Então rode o SQL antes de desenhar o topo do site.

Comment: Você esta tentando matar antes de atirar... esquece! o único jeito que vejo seria mover o valor para o local correto usando css ou javascript...

Comment: Vou te ajudar a entender como o SOpt funciona. É simples, é como na escola. Não é o professor que dá a nota, é o aluno que consegue a nota. O aluno faz o que tem que fazer, se ele **se** ajudar, o professor reconhece isto. Aqui o usuário faz a pergunta ficar em estado que dê para responder, todos que podem terão prazer em ajudar. Mas simplesmente não dá para responder o que não é compreensível. Depois de toda a ajuda já recebida aqui não dá para dizer que há má vontade. Simplesmente ainda está impossível ajudar mais. Faça o favor a você mesmo, nos ajude ajudar você.

Comment: Está reaberta, mas para uma resposta mais precisa você precisa incluir o trecho de código que desenha o que está na imagem.

Comment: Em resumo, você precisa guardar todo o html numa variável, até o ponto em que quer usar o `$qteRegistros`. Só a partir daí você pode começar a emitir a saída. O PHP tem [um buffer que pode ajudar nisso](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ob-get-clean.php).

Comment: Você quer imprimir uma variável que não existe - isso é problema de lógica. Acho que você deve dar mais informações, de preferência o código que você tem.

Comment: Eu só queria capturar uma variável depois de pronta e o @Jader deu exatamente a dica que eu precisava para chegar a solução do meu problema. Fiz isso capturando a variável depois de pronta com jQuery e a reproduzi aonde eu precisava. Jader, fique a vontade em montar uma resposta para que eu avalie.

Comment: Removi meu -1. Finalmente a verdadeira dúvida apareceu... Engraçado que a primeira versão da pergunta tinha [**`Surgiu essa dúvida que deve ser super simples.`**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/35484/1), e como se viu, de simples não tinha nada :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu problema aparentemente é que esta definindo as variáveis no lugar errado como o exemplo abaixo - você quer usar uma variável que ainda não foi definida.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $total_registros; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $PDO = DATABASE...
        $total_registros = $resultado_pdo;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

O correto seria separar a lógica da *view*, mas não vou entar nesse mérito. Apenas crie as variáveis e use-as posteriormente fora dos elementos HTML. Assim você pode definir todas as variáveis e usa-las no HTML.

**pagina.php**

```
//Parte lógica do PHP
<?php
$PDO = DATABASE...
$total_registros = $resultado_pdo;
?>

//composição do HTML
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $total_registros; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Encontrados <?php echo $total_egistros; ?> registros.
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Se eu entendi errado seu problema, me dê mais informações.

Comment: Essa sem dúvida é a melhor solução. Existem outras, manipulando o buffer do php ou por JavaScript, mas são ambas gambiarras.

Comment: JS só com JS-ON e buffer vai ser uma GAMB que eu não acredito que funcione pois sempre será pós echo.

Comment: @bfavaretto, sinto até desconforto colocando *HTML* e a lógica do *PHP* no mesmo arquivo :(

Comment: Uma batalha de cada vez :)

Comment: @Marcos Vinicius, já que marcou a resposta, vou indicar que procure sobre **MVC** como modelo de arquitetura para desenvolvimento. Vai ver que cai como uma luva.